# Good printer review websites?

Tags: website, printer, review

Do you know of any good websites that have fair, up to date printer reviews, including cost per page estimates ? I used to be quite satisfied with http://www.behardware.com/, but their reviews are too outdated now.

The sites [enumerated here](https://superuser.com/questions/78/what-single-site-resource-do-you-use-to-keep-up-with-pc-hardware) are too focused on PC hardware (as opposed to peripherals) for my needs.

Comment: I always thought the StackOverflow/SuperUser style could lend itself to reviews. Perhaps you could post some answers with just the name of a printer and let people vote it up/down depending on their experiance with it. People can also edit the post to give reviews and add comments to explain up/down votes. Might work.

Comment: The cost per page would be very useful as the cost of regular printing soon far exceeds the cost of the printer.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.trustedreviews.com/ is one that I have taken to visiting when checking out potential purchases. Though it is recommended that you try to source reviews from multiple places rather than trusting just one reviewer.

As Pelms points out, in the medium-to-long run consumable costs far outweigh the initial outlay on a printer. TrustdeReviews always includes an estimate of these costs - though bases them on official figures rather than testing themselves (which would take some time that they presumably don't have spare!)

Answer (score 1):

PC Mag - http://www.pcmag.com/category2/0,2806,10,00.asp

CNET - http://reviews.cnet.com/printers/